# Fill pdfinfo metadata with \usekomavar{} not working

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, scrlttr2

I'm using `scrlttr2` and I want to fill in the pdfinfo metadata with already existing `komavars`.

```tex
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject Line}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{8, Valley Str\\
  49584 Livingston}
\setkomavar{place}{Livingston}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

%% use given komavars to populate pdfinfo vars:
\hypersetup{%
  pdfinfo = {%
    Author={\usekomavar{fromname}},
    Subject={\usekomavar{subject}},
    Keywords={KeyA, KeyB, KeyD},
    Producer={Latex with scrlttr2, hyperref},
    Creator={pdflatex}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ACME Inc.\\123, Bull Str\\72348 Washington}
  \opening{Dear Mr Miller}
  \lipsum[1]
  \closing{Sincerely, }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf looks fine.

[image: result of pdfinfo]

Unfortunately, the `\usekomavar{subject}` does not get interpolated, but the
variable's name are retained.

During compilation (using `pdflatex a-minimal.tex`) I get these warnings:

```
`Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
 (hyperref)           removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 19.`
```

Does anybody can help me out?

Andi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The `\usekomavar` and `\usekomavar*` commands are, like all commands where a starred version exists or which can take an optional argument, not fully expandable.

But you can use the optional argument of `\usekomavar` to fill the pdfinfo with the already existing information:

```
\newcommand\mypdfinfo[2]{\hypersetup{pdfinfo={#1=#2}}}
\usekomavar[\mypdfinfo{Author}]{fromname}
\usekomavar[\mypdfinfo{Subject}]{subject}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject Line}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{8, Valley Str\\
  49584 Livingston}
\setkomavar{place}{Livingston}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

%% use given komavars to populate pdfinfo vars:
\newcommand\mypdfinfo[2]{\hypersetup{pdfinfo={#1=#2}}}
\usekomavar[\mypdfinfo{Author}]{fromname}
\usekomavar[\mypdfinfo{Subject}]{subject}

\hypersetup{%
  pdfinfo = {%
    Keywords={KeyA, KeyB, KeyD},
    Producer={Latex with scrlttr2, hyperref},
    Creator={pdflatex}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ACME Inc.\\123, Bull Str\\72348 Washington}
  \opening{Dear Mr Miller}
  \lipsum[1]
  \closing{Sincerely, }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]